# How can I use a 555 timer and a binary counter to determine the frequency of a square wave pulse?

Tags: 555, counter, frequency-measurement, square

I'm trying to build a circuit to determine the frequency of a given square wave pulse. The pulse will be generated by a function generator.

I have a 555 timer, a binary counter, a seven-segment decoder, and a seven-segment display on which I'm supposed to display the output. The assignment also calls for buttons to start the 555 and reset the display. I've been told by a course assistant to use the 555 timer in monostable/one-shot mode, but I don't quite understand how I could use this to determine the pulse frequency.

Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Frequency is # of pulses per unit time.  You have a device that will count pulses and a device that will track time.

Comment: Assuming you already understand what a one-shot does, then if you had a counter that's reset when the one-shot is triggered, and 'gated' the counter using the one-shot output, then the counter could count cycles of the square wave while it was 'gated' and would suddenly stop counting when the one-shot goes back to its inactive state. The number in the counter would be proportional to the frequency, yes?

Comment: Ohh, I see. Thank you both! @vir and periblepsis

Comment: Are you allowed to use two 555s? Just curious.

Comment: You would need a *decade*  (base-10) counter, otherwise your outputs will be base-16.

Comment: @hack makes a point. Either you accept hexadecimal display outputs using a 7-segment decoder with your binary counters or else you use decade counters. But assuming you are okay with the hex output from your 7-segment decoders then [this is what I kind of visualize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84VpU.png). You'd reset the counter on the rising edge(s) of your PB (debounced?) and on the falling edge trigger the one-shot. The output of the one-shot gates the signal's rising edges (or falling edges) and counts them while the one-shot allows. Once the one-shot goes inactive binary counting stops.

Comment: A long, long time ago I built such a thing, using a chain of CD4026s using a kit from Radio Shack (remember them?) It lacked one useful thing: latches for the count (it would blank the display, stop and show the count, blank, etc.) It was crap. But its principle was the same: a timer to set the sample period, and the signal driving the clock.

Comment: I'm only allowed to use 1 of the 555s, and displaying the count on the 7-segment display isn't an issue. I think I can go about implementing it from here - thank you all for your help!